# Converting String value to button name

Tags: java, android

In VB, you use CType to convert a string to a control's name

```
Dim btn1 as Button
Dim Str as String ="btn1"
CType((Str), Button).Text ="your text"
```

how can I achieve the same in java?

Comment: Hi Roberto Thanks for asking and welcome to SO. Your question is very generic which make it difficult to answer. Can you please provide an example of a Java code you tried and what is not working in that code?

Comment: I don't even know which one to try because all am seeing in google is something different from what i want. My aim is to reference a button from a string

Comment: As it stands, it will probably be flagged and closed as too broad. Also, please make an edit to correct the word "archive" to "achieve". You had me confused for a moment what you meant by "archiving this in java".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have buttons with ids (names) like `btn1`, `btn2`, ...., `btn20` and you want to set their text via a for loop, you can use [getIdentifier()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) like this:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
    int id = getResources().getIdentifier("btn" + i, "id", getPackageName());
    Button button = findViewById(id);
    button.setText("something" + i);
}
```

The method `getIdentifier()` takes the id (name) of a `View` and returns its integer id. 
 Then with `findViewById(id)` you get a reference to that `View`.
You may need to qualify both `getResources()` and `getPackageName()` with a valid `Context` if your code is not inside an activity class, like this:

```
int id = context.getResources().getIdentifier("btn" + i, "id", context.getPackageName());
```

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for. This is by far the best solution to my problem. Thanks a million for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean set the text displayed by the Button, then something like :-

```
    Button btn1 = this.findViewById(R.id.done); // Gets the Button as per the id in the layout.
    btn1.setText("Your Text");
```

- in some older versions of Android Studio you had to specifically cast the type from the findViewById, as such the above use `Button btn1 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.done);`

## Additional re Comment :-

> I have up to 20 buttons btn1.........btn20 then i want to use loop to
>   reference this buttons which means i need a string for the btn and an
>   Integer for the number. Concatenating the string & integer will give
>   me the actual button name.

I believe the following may be along the lines of what you want. This creates 20 buttons, adding them to the layout.

Each will have two fields/members set. 
- The Text (the text displayed by the button) field will be set to **My Button #?** (where ? will be 1-20)
- The Tag (a field that can be used as wanted) will be set to a String that is the respective Button's offset in the ArrayList (i.e 0-19).

Each will have an onClickListener added that will issue a Toast detailing the Button's values for the Text and the Tag.

Additionally, the reference a button is achieved by searching for the button accoring to either it's Text value or it's Tag value. Two examples are given where the **0** is searched for, first in the Tag value (will be found as 0)  and then in the Text value (will not be found). The result is written to the Log.

```
public class OtherActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<Button> mButtons = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_other);
        LinearLayout mMainLayout = this.findViewById(R.id.mainlayout);

        // Add the 20 buttons dynamically assigning Text and a Tag
        for (int i=0; i < 20; i++) {
            Button current_button = new Button(this);
            current_button.setText("My Button #" + String.valueOf(i + 1));
            current_button.setTag(String.valueOf(i));
            mButtons.add(current_button);
            mMainLayout.addView(current_button);
            current_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(
                            v.getContext(),
                            "You CLicked on the Buttton with Text as :-" + ((Button) v).getText().toString() + " Tag as " + ((Button)v).getTag(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show();
                }
            });
        }

        // Search for the button according to some text    
        // Should work as Tag has been set to 0
        Button button_to_use = findButtonByTagOrText("0",true,mButtons);
        if (button_to_use != null) {
            Log.d("BUTTONFINDRESULT","Button 0 Found according to the Tag");
        } else {
            Log.d("BUTTONFINDRESULT","Button 0 NOT FOUND acording to Tag");
        }

        //Will not find button as text will not be o but will instead be My Button #1 (for the first button)
        button_to_use = findButtonByTagOrText("0", false,mButtons);
        if (button_to_use != null) {
            Log.d("BUTTONFINDRESULT","Button 0 Found according to the Text");
        } else {
            Log.d("BUTTONFINDRESULT","Button 0 NOT FOUND acording to Text");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Find the button according to it's TAG or Text
     * @param value_to_find     The String to find
     * @param look_for_tag      true if to look at the Tag, false if to look at the Text
     * @param button_list       The ArrayList<Button> aka the list of buttons
     * @return                  null if not found, else the Button object
     */
    private Button findButtonByTagOrText(String value_to_find, boolean look_for_tag, ArrayList<Button> button_list) {
        Button rv = null;
        String compare_string;
        for (Button b: button_list) {
            if (look_for_tag) {
                compare_string = (String) b.getTag();
            } else {
                compare_string = b.getText().toString();
            }
            if (value_to_find.equals(compare_string)) {
                return b;
            }
        }
        return rv; // Note returned button will be null if text not found.
    }
}
```

The result is that the App when run appears as :-

[image]

- Note the DONE button was in the layout, it can be ignored as it isn't used or handled in the code above.

CLicking a buttons displays a Toast according to the button clicked e.g. :-

[image]

The Log includes (as expected) :-

```
04-13 22:41:20.068 15617-15617/? D/BUTTONFINDRESULT: Button 0 Found according to the Tag
04-13 22:41:20.068 15617-15617/? D/BUTTONFINDRESULT: Button 0 NOT FOUND acording to Text
```

Comment: I have up to 20 buttons btn1.........btn20 then i want to use loop to reference this buttons which means i need a string for the btn and an Integer for the number.  Concatenating the string & integer will give me the actual button name.

Comment: @Roberto that is not the question you asked, it's another and different question.